# Documents, Music, Downloads, Desktop files not showing

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, hidden-files

Suddenly my Ubuntu 14.04 is not showing any Desktop files or folders. Additionally when I click on Documents, Music, Pictures, Downloads, or Videos, I see this error message:

[image: error screenshot]

Output for running `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` is:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Share"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

I also lost all of all files located at `/home/username/A` which directory is currently lost/hidden.

**How I can get back all files? And get access to Documents, Music, Pictures, Downloads, and Videos?**

Comment: There is an unexpected "|" at the end of the XDG_MUSIC_DIR line. Perhaps this causes the whole `user-dirs.dirs` file to be ignored? Please remove this and try again.

Comment: @Jos That's the cursor, not a pipe.

Comment: Did you install your system in a language different from English?

Comment: Do you know the name of one of the files you're missing and can you try `sudo updatedb&&locate szNameOfFile`?  We can then take it from there.  Also, do a `smartctl --all /dev/XdY` of the device you're having trouble with and post that to http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide the link back into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed nothing. I just created five directories named **Documents**,**Music**,**Pictures**,**Downloads**, **Videos** inside */home/partho/* and dragged and dropped the directories to the bookmarks bar left at the screen.

See the [video](https://youtu.be/nYHAW4hDTMg) how I dragged and drop.

Now Documents,Music,Pictures,Downloads,Videos are created as bookmarks and they are now accessible but lost data couldn't be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually the fault of some installed packages that unexpectedly hide user's files. In my case, it was [LinuxDC++](https://launchpad.net/linuxdcpp). In such a scenario, one's files are usually in the hidden folders in `home` directory. I found mine in one of the FileLists in `.dc++` folder.

To view hidden files/folders, press `Ctrl`+`H` in the desired directory. The files/folders whose names begin with a `.` are the hidden ones; you are most likely to find your files there.